# How to execute a perl script on crontab

Tags: perl, cron

I have written a perl script test.pl which uses a subroutine written in another file testing .pm. I'm able to run this script successfully manually, but when I run the same script on crontab, I get the following error
**`Can't locate testing.pm in @INC`**
I have changed the permissions of both the files to execute permission and used **`"use testing"`** at the top of the script. How can I successfully run the script on crontab.

**`Crontab : */2 * * * *  PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/home/test/testing.pm /home/test/test.pl > /home/test/test.log 2>&1`**

**

```
test.pl  
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use DBI;
 use warnings;
 use Time::Piece;
 use HTML::Entities;
 use lib '/home/test';
 use testing
# Connecting to the database #
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost;mysql_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock","root","password", {'RaiseError' => 1});
# my $dob = '2009-04-21 00:00:00';
my $dob = '2009-04-22 00:00:00';
#my $dob = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
print "\ndob : $dob\n";
$name="test";
$number=1;
$email="test@test.com"
$id="123";
if ($mail==0)
{
 send_msg(0,$name,$number,$email,$aid);
}
if ($sms==0)
{
 send_msg(1,$name,$number,$email,$id);
}
}
sub send_msg {
   my ($type,$name,$number,$email,$id) = @_;
   $sql7 = "select Sms,email from settings where Id='$id'";
   $sth7 = $dbh->prepare($sql7);
   $sth7->execute
   or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
   my ($sms,$email)=$sth7->fetchrow_array();
   my $xml=testing::xml($type,$name,$number,$email,$sms,$email);    
}
```

**

Comment: This is a subset of the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753670/why-cant-my-perl-script-load-a-module-when-run-by-cron?rq=1

Comment: just one suggestion `use strict;`

Comment: @Ganesh use strict - How does it affect the execution on crontab

Comment: @Rudra: no it will not affect execution in crontab, i just suggested it since you are using `my` for some variables only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to tell your Perl binary where to look for `testing.pm`. You could do this in your crontab:

```
0 * * * * PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/directory/where/testing.pm/lives perl myperlscript.pl
```

Or you could do it in your .pl script by using `use lib`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '/directory/where/testing.pm/lives';
...
```

Update:

Your edited question shows several problems:

1. Your crontab says `PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/home/test/testing.pm`. You need to add the *directory* to `PERL5LIB` not the path to the file. The correct version would be: `PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/home/test'.
2. Your `test.pl` says `use testing`. There is no semicolon to be found anywhere after `testing`.

Comment: Then go back to your question, edit the question and show us some code: How does your crontab look like? How does your `test.pl` look like?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways of fixing this. My preference would be to keep the crontab simple and add something like :

```
 use FindBin qw($Bin);
 use lib "$Bin/../lib";
```

This assumes that the library file is in a fixed relationship to the perl script. The example comes from [documentation for the `FindBin` module](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/lib/FindBin.pm).

Comment: The documentation link is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `testing.pm` in your @INC array? If not, you can [add paths](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations) to @INC through the PERL5LIB environment variable:

```
env PERL5LIB=/path/to/testing.pm perl test.pl
```

Or use the lib module with a different path -- `use lib qw#/path/to/testing.pm#;` -- at the top of your script.
Hope that sorts you...